# Floating Search Bar package in flutter remove back arrow

Tags: flutter, dart, search, package

I want to remove this back arrow from this Floating Search Bar
I tried making its `iconColor:  Colors.transparent,` but it still talking the space,
I little help will be appreciated thanks

[image]

```
return FloatingSearchBar(
          controller: widget.controller,
          elevation: 2,
      
          hint: 'search .. ',
          border: const BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.none),
          margins: widget.margins,
          // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.w, 10.w, 2.w, 0),
          iconColor:  AppColors.primaryColor,
          scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.w, bottom: 56.w),
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          transitionCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          debounceDelay: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          onQueryChanged: widget.onQueryChanged,
          onFocusChanged: widget.onFocusChanged,
          transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.r),
          actions: [
            FloatingSearchBarAction(
                showIfOpened: true,
                child: Image.asset(
                  AppImages.search,
                  width: 60.w,
                  height: 25.w,
                ))
          ],
```

Comment: This floating search bar? https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar

Comment: yeah that one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
 automaticallyImplyBackButton: false,
```